# How to submit nullable input values with validation without getting error msg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

When I try to submit, without the non-required field I get an error msg due to the validation...So how can I submit the input field without disabling all the validation for the non-required field(address,phone)?

**JQUERY**

```
var contact_fs_name = $('#lb_firstname').val(); //required
var contact_ls_name = $('#lb_lastname').val(); //required
var contact_ur_name = $('#lb_email').val(); //required
var contact_pass = $('lb_password').val(); //required
var contact_address = $('#lb_address').val(); // can be null,empty
var contact_phone = $('#lb_phone').val(); // can be null,empty

if (contact_fs_name === "" || contact_ls_name === "" || contact_ur_name === "" || contact_pass === ""){
        alert("Please fill in all fields");

    } else if (!contact_address.match(/^(?=.*[a-z]).{3,20}$/)){

        alert("error_addr!");

    } else if (contact_phone.length < 10) {

        alert("error_phone!");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in an additional conditional. Check for the empty or null value, if not null or '' check validation.

See below:

```js
var contact_fs_name = $('#lb_firstname').val(); //required
var contact_ls_name = $('#lb_lastname').val(); //required
var contact_ur_name = $('#lb_email').val(); //required
var contact_pass = $('lb_password').val(); //required
var contact_address = $('#lb_address').val(); // can be null,empty
var contact_phone = $('#lb_phone').val(); // can be null,empty

if (contact_fs_name === "" || contact_ls_name === "" || contact_ur_name === "" || contact_pass === ""){
        alert("Please fill in all fields");
} else if (contact_address != '' && contact_address != null){
  if (!contact_address.match(/^(?=.*[a-z]).{3,20}$/)){
    alert("error_addr!");
  }
} else if(contact_phone != '' && contact_phone != null) {
    if (contact_phone.length < 10) {
      alert("error_phone!");
    }
}
```

Comment: how would it go on the php side - wouldl that work                                                           else if(isset($_POST['#lb_address']) && !preg_match ('%^[A-Za-z\.\' \-]{2,30}$%', $_POST['#lb_addressj'])) {
        echo "Please enter a valid address!";
        exit();
    }

Comment: What error are you trying to avoid. The `alert()` that says 'error_phone!' or a server side error?

Comment: I want to avoid both client/server error but without disabling the validation on any side, the jquery work i believe but what about for php

Comment: The `isset()` method checks if the value is 'set' or not null so that should work. Basically just mirroring the behavior from js to php.

Comment: `isset()` checks if the variable is set. '' does count as being set, where NULL doesn't. Might want to use `empty()`

Comment: just something more, can u tell me if !=='' would work instead of !='' that u choose?

Comment: Yeah you can. Keep in mind, null == "" will return true. null === "" will return false